# Multiple GroupBy in 1 linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I cannot seem to combine 2 GroupBy statements in 1 linq expression..

For now i'm doing something like this:

```
double maxInvestment = 0;

foreach (var playerAction in TotalUserActions.GroupBy(p => p.Player))
{
    var MaxInvestmentPerPlayer = playerAction.GroupBy(p => p.RoundId)
                                             .Select(p => p.LastOrDefault())
                                             .Sum(p=> p.BetSize);

    if(MaxInvestmentPerPlayer > maxInvestment)
        maxInvestment = MaxInvestmentPerPlayer;
}
```

What I would like to do is something like this...

```
double maxInvestment = TotalUserActions.GroupBy(p => p.Player)
                                       .GroupBy(p => p.RoundId)
                                       .Select(p => p.LastOrDefault())
                                       .Sum(p=> p.BetSize);
```

But that wont work.. Can someone help me on this?

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have more than one group by as so - is the goal simply group by Player *and* RoundId .. and if not, what is the goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is what you want, the key takeaway being the inner query is wrapped in an outer call to `Select()`:

```
var maxInvestment = TotalUserActions.GroupBy(p => p.Player)
                                    .Select(g => g.GroupBy(x => x.RoundId)
                                                  .Select(x => x.LastOrDefault())
                                                  .Sum(x => x.BetSize))
                                    .Max();
```

I do question your use of `LastOrDefault()` though as, since you have not specified any ordering, you may as well use `FirstOrDefault()` and save the hassle of skipping to the last element.

Comment: Thanks alot lc, that was exactly what I was looking for!
It also makes me understand these groupby queries a bit more!

The lastOrDefault() was very crucial for my approach, since the betSizes of my UserActions are always total values.